# Powershell script to find duplicate Windows processes and kill them

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a PS script that will look for a specific process in Windows and kill all duplicates found, but leaves one running.

The script I was using with some success, I found here, and it looks like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process |
    Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -like 'wfshell*'} |
    Sort-Object -Property ElapsedTime |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    ForEach-Object {Stop-Process $_.IDProcess} -Confirm:$false
```

The problem is we have the script scheduled to run on user logoff, and if a user logs in and then logs off more than once, the script kills the final running process, and not just the duplicate.

So I am trying to figure out how to write a statement to the effect of: while process.exe > 1, kill process.exe. I am not very familiar with PS though and I'm struggling to write anything that works. My knowledge is limited to an intro to python course. Any pointers to what I should be looking at would be greatly appreciated! Thank you, Jonathan

Comment: It looks like your command should work, though it can be simplified to: `Get-Process -Name wfshell* | Sort-Object StartTime -Descending | 
 Select-Object -Skip First 1 | Stop-Process` - in what way isn't it working?

Comment: * `... | Select-Object -Skip 1 ...` (no First keyword there)

Comment: @SagePourpre, it appears that the OP wants to kill all processes except the first one.

Comment: @JonathanV, how does the user logoff more than once?

Comment: @lit what is happening is when the user logs in, they are seeing two processes running (wfshell.exe) when there should only be one running. Once they disconnect (which is what I should have said instead of log off, please excuse my mis-type there), the script kills the duplicate process, and only one instance of wfshell.exe is running. When they log back in, only one instance of wfshell.exe remains running. They then disconnect again, which kills the remaining process, and now no wfshell.exe processes are running, which is what we are trying to avoid. Thank you.  -Jonathan